# ANCOVA power analysis using groups differing in sizes

Tags: statistical-power, gpower

For my research, I'm calculating the required sample with G*Power, using effect sizes estimates.

I have 1 scale dependent variable and a 4 x 2 design. I especially care about comparing 1 group to the other 3, which is why I'd like to divide the participants into the groups in ratio 4:2:2:2.

I can integrate interaction effects into my power analysis in the degrees of freedom ([using this guide](https://www.xlstat.com/en/solutions/features/statistical-power-for-anova-ancova-repeated-measures-anova)). However, I can't seem to find how to correct the degrees of freedom for the fact that the groups differ in sizes. Is there a simple way to do that?